# Switching between list and plain text across article and presentation mode in beamerarticle

Tags: beamer, lists, overlays, presentations, beamerarticle

I use beamerarticle to write lecture notes, but use a lot of lists on the slides that I don't need in lecture mode. Is there a way to toggle between a list and a plain text environment as in the following code, but without all the `\only` commands?

```
% toggle between line 1 and lines 2-3 for slides or notes
%\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer} 

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[noxcolor]{beamerarticle}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\only<presentation>{\begin{itemize}[<+->]}
\only<presentation>{ \item} Am I  a list
\only<presentation>{ \item}or just a line of text?
\only<presentation>{\end{itemize}}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Specifically, I'm looking for a code that will require at most one wrapper, not a separate addition to each individual `\item`, and it should still be compatible with overlay specifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER:**

```
\def\presentation{1}

\ifnum\presentation=1
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\newenvironment{mitemize}[1][]{\def\Arg{#1}\ifx\Arg\empty\itemize\else\itemize[#1]\fi}{\enditemize}
\else
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[noxcolor]{beamerarticle}
%\let\olditemize\itemize
%\let\endolditemize\enditemize
\newenvironment{mitemize}[1][]{\let\item\relax
}{}
%\renewenvironment{itemize}[1][]{\def\Arg{#1}\def\Ignored{<+->}\olditemize\ifx\Arg\empty\relax\else\ifx\Arg\Ignored\relax\else[#1]\fi\fi}{\endolditemize}
\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item am I  a list
\item or just a line of text?
\end{itemize}

\begin{mitemize}[<+->]
\item am I  a list
\item or just a line of text?
\end{mitemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

**OLD ANSWERS:**

Here is a way:

```
% define as 1 for presentation or another number else.
\def\presentation{1}

\ifnum\presentation=1
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\newenvironment{mitemize}[1][]{\itemize[#1]\let\mitem\item}{\enditemize}

\else
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[noxcolor]{beamerarticle}
\newenvironment{mitemize}[1][]{\let\mitem\relax}{}
\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{mitemize}
\mitem am I  a list
\mitem or just a line of text?
\end{mitemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

If you want to use itemize environment in the non-presentation mode just a few times, try the `mitemize` environment only for these cases that will work as itemize in every mode... In other case the result will be your required:

```
\def\presentation{0}

\ifnum\presentation=1
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext]{beamer}
\newenvironment{mitemize}[1][]{\def\Arg{#1}\itemize\ifx\Arg\empty\relax\else[#1]\fi}{\enditemize}
\else
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[noxcolor]{beamerarticle}
\let\olditemize\itemize
\let\endolditemize\enditemize
\renewenvironment{itemize}[1][]{\let\item\relax
}{\endolditemize}
\newenvironment{mitemize}[1][]{\def\Arg{#1}\olditemize\ifx\Arg\empty\relax\else[#1]\fi}{\endolditemize}
\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item am I  a list
\item or just a line of text?
\end{itemize}

\begin{mitemize}
\item am I  a list
\item or just a line of text?
\end{mitemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand all the code, but it doesn't make the list code itself any simpler, does it? What I'm looking to avoid is to have to add code to every single item; I'll update the question to clarify.

Comment: @mimuller edited

Comment: Cool, thanks! Waiting to see if there's a way that would make it easier to update the code that I already have, and wouldn't require editing each line. But it's elegant!

Comment: @mimuller Added a way for this requirement too .. but may be if you want to use a itemize inside your non presentation you should use the `mitemize` environment.

Comment: oh perfect! Now it's exactly what I need, thanks!!

Comment: Added the optional argument too in the last seconds... Welcome.

Comment: Actually, the bottom code doesn't compile on my end right now. It says "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item." Will check again when I come back.

Comment: Sorry .. lost the fact that an empty argument as optional argument would cause problems ... Fixed

Comment: Perfect! I'll accept your answer, but maybe for others who would look to this code too, let me just point out that as written, it's the itemize environment that turns into text, and the mitemize remains a list in the article mode. The opposite may be more intuitive, but I think I can adjust it.

Comment: @mimuller you asked to not make many changes and I supposed that in the most of the cases you want the already written code of `itemize` to be changed automatically...   This is why I redefined the original `itemize` ... I will add an answer (that is easier too) for `mitemize` environment to give the inline text in article mode and to be as itemize in presentation mode. Did I understood correct now?

Comment: fair enough. :) Last question though if I may... the current code does not work with overlay specification `[<+->]`. Is that an easy fix?

Comment: Please update your question with such an example ...

Comment: Just added the overlay to the question.

Comment: @mimuller Edited!

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Comment: I adapted the code slightly for my needs... in articlemode I wrote:
\let\olditemize\itemize
\let\olditem\item
\let\endolditemize\enditemize
\newenvironment{mitemize}[1][]{\let\item\relax}{}
\renewenvironment{itemize}[1][]{\let\item\olditem\def\Arg{#1}\ifx\Arg\empty\olditemize\else\olditemize[#1]\fi}{\endolditemize}

This has the benefit that when an `itemize` list is nested inside an `mitemize` list, then only the "mitem"s are transformed into plain text. (Before, I would get an error message regarding missing items in the nested list.)

Comment: Or, even better \newenvironment{mitemize}[1][]{\let\item\relax}{\ignorespacesafterend} in there, to get rid of unintended white space.

Comment: nice ... Happy TeXing!