# How can I make sure the overlay specification doesn't print in beamerarticle?

Tags: beamer, macros, overlays

I had to adapt the itemize environment for a [separate concern](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505489/switching-between-list-and-plain-text-across-article-and-presentation-mode-in-be), but in doing so I somehow messed with the `\item` command in a way where it now prints the overlay specification in `article` mode. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[noxcolor]{beamerarticle}

\let\olditemize\itemize
\let\olditem\item
\let\endolditemize\enditemize
\newenvironment{newitemize}[1][]{%
   \let\item\olditem%
   \def\Arg{#1}%
   \ifx\Arg\empty\olditemize\else\olditemize[#1]\fi%
   }{%
   \endolditemize%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{newitemize}
\item<2-> Why does it print the overlay specification?
\end{newitemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What I don't understand is the following: I save all the original parts of the `itemize` list to `olditemize` first, and then define `newitemize` from there. But manifestly this doesn't leave me exactly with what I started out with, because the original `itemize` does not print the overlay specification in `article` mode.

Could someone please explain why (and in what ways) my ´newitemize´ is different from the standard ´itemize´?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make LaTeX to ignore the overlay option in this situation that doesn't have a meaning. In other case it will be printed.

In my way I redefine the `\item` command to ignore this argument (inside `<>`):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[noxcolor]{beamerarticle}

\let\olditemize\itemize
\let\olditem\item
\let\endolditemize\enditemize
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{newitemize}[1][]{%
   \def\item{\@ifnextchar<
   {\WithOverlay}
   {\WithoutOverlay}
   }
   \def\WithOverlay<##1>
   {\olditem}
   \def\WithoutOverlay
   {\olditem}%
   \def\Arg{#1}%
   \ifx\Arg\empty\olditemize\else\olditemize[#1]\fi%
   }{%
   \endolditemize%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{newitemize}
\item<2-> Why does it print the overlay specification?
\end{newitemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

PS: Your question is why. So, my answer is not a suggestion to your problems (of your previous question) but a way to give you understand how you could go on. (Seems you learn fast... Happy TeXing!)